# Trigger and Identity causing a "row value(s) updated or deleted either do not make the row unique or they alter multple rows" error during update

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, triggers, visual-c#-express-2010

I am using Visual C# 2010 Express to create a table in SQL Server 2008. The column definitions are as follows:

```
SEQ -- type int, primary key, don't allow nulls
STID -- type int, don't allow nulls
CCODE -- type int, don't allow nulls
SCORE -- type int, don't allow nulls
ADDTIME -- type datetime, allow nulls
```

Then I set SEQ's "Is Identity" flag to be YES, the seed as 10001, and the increment as 1.

Next, I add a trigger for the table like this:

```
ALTER TRIGGER TRIG_ENROLL
ON dbo.ENROLL
FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    UPDATE t
    SET ADDTIME = GETDATE()
    FROM [dbo].[ENROLL] t
    JOIN inserted i ON i.SEQ = t.SEQ
END
```

Finally, I add data directly to the table using the "Show Table Data" interface. Inserting the records are ok, as the ADDTIME and SEQ are automatically filled after I type the data, right click the row and select Execute SQL. However, when I update the SCORE column of an existing record, I get the following error:

> Row value(s) updated or deleted either do not make the row unique or they alter multiple rows(2 rows)

I suspect it's the SEQ and the trigger that cause the problem. When I remove the trigger, updating the record does not cause any error. But what is the error?

In fact, a stranger thing is that when I try to use another computer and do the same procedures (build the table, add the trigger, insert the records, and then update them) using the same software, the error does not occur. Is it some kind of settings issue that I have overlooked?

Comment: Your definition at the top is very confusing due to the double-negatives in the column comments. I suspect they're saying the opposite of what you're trying to - e.g. "don't allow not null" would tend to imply that `null` is allowed and I suspect you're trying to say the opposite. As to your actual problem, it's probably one that can be addressed just by adding `SET NOCOUNT ON` at the top of the trigger. (Most templates for triggers these days would include that line anyway)

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Thanks for pointing it out, yes they should be allow nulls instead, coz I am too used to the not null in MySQL table definitions. I have changed them. And yes, the `SET NOCOUNT ON` really works. You can make it as an answer if you like to. My remaining question is: Why does the 2nd computer work without this `SET NOCOUNT ON` line?